# Problem with array of class objects leads to crash

Tags: c++

So I am making a textbased RPG and I wanted to have multiple enemy encounter at once. So I modified my function that determines whether an object of the class Monster, to fill in the Monster(s) into an array of the class monster and set the objects bool to true, as you can see here:

```
Monster * Map::checkRandomEncounter()
{

    Monster* monster = new Monster[3];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {

        int roll = Random(0, 20);
        if (roll <= 5)
        {
//No encounter
            return 0;
        }

        else if (roll > 6 && roll < 10)
        {
            monster[i] = Monster();
            monster[i].giveID("Orc", 10, 8, 200, 100, 1, "Short Sword", 2, 7);

            monster[i].isFilled();
            std::cout << "You encounter an Orc!" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Prepare for battle!" << std::endl;
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
        else if (roll >= 11 && roll <= 15)
        {
            monster[i] = Monster();
            monster[i].giveID("Goblin", 6, 6, 100, 75, 0, "Dagger", 1, 5);

            monster[i].isFilled();
            std::cout << "You encounter a Goblin!" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Prepare for battle!" << std::endl;
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
        else if (roll >= 16 && roll <= 19)
        {
            monster[i] = Monster();
            monster[i].giveID("Ogre", 20, 12, 500, 200, 2, "Club", 3, 8);
            monster[i].isFilled();

            std::cout << "You encounter an Ogre!" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Prepare for battle!" << std::endl;
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
        else if (roll == 20)
        {
            monster[i] = Monster();
            monster[i].giveID("Orc Lord",
                              25,
                              15,
                              2000,
                              1000,
                              5,
                              "Two Handed Sword",
                              5,
                              20);
            monster[i].isFilled();

            std::cout << "You encounter an Orc Lord!" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Prepare for battle!" << std::endl;
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return monster;
}
```

The function above will be called in my main function, which looks like this:

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    Map gameMap;

    Player mainPlayer;
    mainPlayer.createClass();

    //Beginn adventure
    bool done = false;
    while (done == false)
    {
        // Each Loop Cycle outputs player pos and selection menu
        gameMap.printPlayerPos();

        int selection = 1;
        std::cout << "1) Move 2) Rest 3) View Stats 4) Quit: ";
        std::cin >> selection;

        Monster* monster = 0;
        switch (selection)
        {
            case 1: // Move the player
                gameMap.movePlayer();

                if (gameMap.getPlayerXPos() == 2
                        && gameMap.getPlayerYPos() == 3)
                {
                    std::cout << "You see a store nearby !" << std::endl;
                }

                if (gameMap.getPlayerXPos() == 2
                        && gameMap.getPlayerYPos() == 4)
                {
                    Store store;
                    store.enter();
                    store.showInventory(mainPlayer);
                }

                //Check for a random encounter
                //returns a null pointer if no encounter happened
                monster = gameMap.checkRandomEncounter();

                //'monster' not null, start battle script
                if (monster != 0)
                {
                    //Loop until a break statement
                    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                    {
                        //Display Hitpoints
                        mainPlayer.displayHitPoints();
                        monster[i].displayHitPoints();
                        std::cout << std::endl;

                        //Players turn to attack first
                        **bool runAway = mainPlayer.attack(monster, mainPlayer);** // Crash happening in this area

                        if (runAway) // Player flees
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        if (monster[i].isDead())
                        {
                            mainPlayer.victory(monster->getXPReward(),
                                               monster->getGoldReward());
                            mainPlayer.levelUp(mainPlayer);

                        }
                        break;

                        //Monster attacks
                        monster[i].attack(mainPlayer);

                        if (mainPlayer.isDead())
                        {
                            mainPlayer.gameOver();
                            done = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    //Pointer to Monster must destroy created instance of Monster
                    //to make sure that there is no Memory leak

                }
                delete monster;
                monster = 0;

                break;
            case 2: // resting
                mainPlayer.rest();
                monster = gameMap.checkRandomEncounter();

                //'monster' not null, start battle script
                monster = gameMap.checkRandomEncounter();

                //'monster' not null, start battle script
                if (monster != 0)
                {
                    //Loop until a break statement
                    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                    {
                        //Display Hitpoints
                        mainPlayer.displayHitPoints();
                        monster[i].displayHitPoints();
                        std::cout << std::endl;

                        //Players turn to attack first
                        bool runAway = mainPlayer.attack(monster, mainPlayer);

                        if (runAway) // Player flees
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        if (monster[i].isDead())
                        {
                            mainPlayer.victory(monster->getXPReward(),
                                               monster->getGoldReward());
                            mainPlayer.levelUp(mainPlayer);

                        }
                        break;

                        //Monster attacks
                        monster[i].attack(mainPlayer);

                        if (mainPlayer.isDead())
                        {
                            mainPlayer.gameOver();
                            done = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    //Pointer to Monster must destroy created instance of Monster
                    //to make sure that there is no Memory leak

                }
                delete monster;
                monster = 0;

                break;
            case 3: // viewing stats
                mainPlayer.viewStats();
                break;
            case 4: // quitting
                done = true;
                break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and finally the last puzzle piece, the function where the player attacks the Monster(s):

```
bool Player::attack(Monster Monster[], Player& Player)
{
    int ArmorBefore = 0;

    int Roll = 0;
    int selection = 1;
    int i;

    if (Monster[0].isFilled() == true)
    {
        i = 0;
    }
    else if (Monster[1].isFilled() == true)
    {
        i = 1;
    }
    else if (Monster[2].isFilled() == true)
    {
        i = 2;
    }

    if (Monster[i].isFilled() == true)
    {

        std::cout << "1) Attack 2) Run 3) Cast Spell 4) Use Item: ";
        std::cin >> selection;
        std::cout << std::endl;

        switch (selection)
        {
            case 1: // Player fights
                std::cout << " You attack an " << Monster[i].getName()
                        << " with a " << mWeapon.mName << std::endl;

                if (Random(0, 20) < mAccuracy) // Player hits Monster
                {
                    int damage = Random(mWeapon.mDamageRange);
                    int totalDamage = damage - Monster[i].getArmor();

                    if (totalDamage <= 0) // Armor is equal or higher than player atk
                    {
                        std::cout << "Your attack failed to penetrate "
                                << Monster[i].getName() << "'s armor !"
                                << std::endl;
                        return false;
                    }
                    else // Attack is higher than Monsters armor
                    {
                        std::cout << "You hit " << Monster[i].getName()
                                << " for " << totalDamage << " damage !"
                                << std::endl;
                        // Subtract dmg from Monsters hp
                        Monster[i].takeDamage(totalDamage);
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                else // Player Misses
                {
                    std::cout << "You miss !" << std::endl;
                }
                std::cout << std::endl;
                return false;
                break;
            case 2: // Player runs with a 25% chance
                Roll = Random(1, 4);

                if (Roll == 1) // Success
                {
                    std::cout << "You run away !" << std::endl;
                    return true; // <- Return out of the function
                }
                else
                {
                    std::cout << "You failed to escape !" << std::endl;
                    return false;
                }
            case 3: // Casting Spell
            {
                int SpellSelect;
                // Spells for the Fighter
                if (Player.mClassName == "Fighter")
                {

                    std::cout << std::endl;
                    std::cout << "1) Shield 2) Mighty Blow: ";
                    std::cin >> SpellSelect;
                    if (SpellSelect == 1)
                    {
                        if (Player.mMagicPoints >= 10) // checks for player mana
                        {
                            std::cout << "You cast a mighty shield!"
                                    << std::endl;
                            ArmorBefore = Player.mArmor;
                            Player.shield(Player);
                            Player.mMagicPoints -= 10;

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            std::cout << "Not enough Mana" << std::endl;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (Player.mMagicPoints >= 5) // casting Mighty Blow
                        {
                            int damage = Random(mMightyBlow.mDamageRange);
                            std::cout
                                    << "You strike with all your might ! and Deal "
                                    << damage << " damage !" << std::endl;
                            Monster[i].takeDamage(damage);
                            Player.mMagicPoints -= 5;
                            return false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            std::cout << "Not enough Mana" << std::endl;
                            return false;
                        }
                    }

                }
                //Spells for the Wizard
                else if (Player.mClassName == "Wizard")
                {
                    std::cout << "1) Fireball";
                    std::cin >> SpellSelect;

                    if (Player.mMagicPoints >= 45)
                    {
                        int damage = Random(mFireball.mDamageRange);
                        std::cout << "You cast a Fireball and deal " << damage
                                << " damage !" << std::endl;
                        Monster[i].takeDamage(damage);
                        Player.mMagicPoints -= 45;
                        return false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        std::cout << "Not enough Mana" << std::endl;
                        return false;
                    }

                }
                // Spells for the Cleric
                else if (Player.mClassName == "Cleric")
                {
                    std::cout << "1) Magic Missile";
                    std::cin >> SpellSelect;

                    if (Player.mMagicPoints >= 35)
                    {
                        int damage = Random(mMagicMissile.mDamageRange);
                        std::cout << "You cast a Magic Missile and deal "
                                << damage << " damage !" << std::endl;
                        Monster[i].takeDamage(damage);
                        Player.mMagicPoints -= 35;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        std::cout << "Not enough Mana" << std::endl;
                        return false;
                    }

                }

            }
            case 4: // using Item
                int invSlot;
                std::cout << "1) HP Potion: ";
                std::cin >> invSlot;

                if (invSlot == 1) // Potion slot
                {
                    if (mHPot.mAmount.size() > 0)
                    {
                        std::cout << "You used a Potion and healed for 5 HP !"
                                << std::endl;
                        int currentSize = mHPot.mAmount.size();
                        mHPot.mAmount.resize(currentSize - 1);
                        Player.mHitPoints += 5;
                        if (Player.mHitPoints > Player.mMaxHitPoints)
                        {
                            Player.mHitPoints = Player.mMaxHitPoints;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        std::cout << "You have no Potions!" << std::endl;
                        return false;
                    }

                }
                else // wrong slot
                {
                    std::cout << "No Item found!" << std::endl;
                    return false;
                }

        }
        // Clearing stat boosts
        if (Player.shield(Player) == true)
        {
            Player.mArmor = ArmorBefore;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

When I run the game, I sometimes have the problem, that after filling in a Monster in a slot of the array, no battle will be triggered. And if a battle will be triggered, I get a crash with an error report every time, which says:

_CrtlValidHeadPointer(block)

I guess that something with my pointer is not functioning well.... but since I am a beginner I am pretty much stuck. I would be very grateful for some enlightenment :)

Comment: Something happening every time is a blessing from the gods. Run the debugger, wait for the crash, inspect the backtrace for clues.

Comment: Yeah, I did that. Seems to get stuck somewhere in main, when it checks the bool. But from my point of view, it should be fine... It either gets true or false returned and should from there on go on. What I completely don't get is why it sometimes fills in data in the array and skips the battle part, written in the attack function.

Comment: Unrelated (possibly): `delete monster;`  wrong `delete`. `monster` is an array and needs `delete[]`.

Comment: use std::vector and std::shared_ptr - life will improve immeasurably

Comment: Not the answer, but in *modern C++™* the manual use of `new/delete` is discouraged, except if you have very good reasons for it. In 99% cases containers and/or smart pointers are better. Also, you have some formatting problems...

Comment: You have a for loop in your `checkRandomEncounter` method that is generating a random number, then checking it to determine monster slots.  If you roll a 6, followed by a 4, then even though you filled in a monster you are returning 0 and therefore no encounter. You have a 25% chance of rolling "no encounter" and since the loop is executing 3 times, you could potentially generate 2 monsters and then still return 0 for "no encounters"

Comment: Highlite where in the code the crash takes place. You haven't provided enough code for us to run the program and find out ourselves. Note that you have several bugs in this code and probably more in that which you have not shown.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat the formatting errors could be a result of my edit.

Comment: A tactical note: When you find yourself with a `case` in a `switch` that contains more than a few lines of code, consider making a function. Not only does this group your code a bit better and make it easier to read, this can sometimes eliminate bugs where data from one case pollutes another.

Comment: tactical note: Rather than  a number with a comment explaining it (eg. `case 1: // Player fights`) define a constant (an enumerated type is the bomb if you have several related numbers) with a descriptive name instead (eg constexpr int FIGHT = 1;` and later `case FIGHT:`). This makes your code easier to read.

Comment: @StringOfArrays: I'd suggest to post this to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Note: CodeReview only deals in code that works but could work better. It's a great place to go AFTER the bugs have been fixed up, but read through the [How to Ask]9https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/asking) help pages first.

Comment: @pstrjds THANKS! that fixed the issue with no fight happening. Now I still have the one where the game crashes. It must've something to do with the return of the bool

Answer (score 3):

This place can potentially call undefined behavior and crash:

```
int i;

if (Monster[0].isFilled() == true)
{
    i = 0;
}
else if (Monster[1].isFilled() == true)
{
    i = 1;
}   
else if (Monster[2].isFilled() == true)
{
    i = 2;
}
/*else // one of solutions
 break;*/

//"i" can be unset! and can have any value from INT_MIN to INT_MAX!

    if (Monster[i].isFilled() == true) //potentially index over array
    {
```

Also there are memory leaks and undefined behavior with memory management:

```
Monster* monster = new Monster[3];
...
delete monster
```

must be `delete [] monster`

but it is recommended to use smart pointers, vector, array, etc, for memory management